# Generate database blob files to save data

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, database

I'd like to save some images (jpeg) into a blob file. I don't have any idea to start, how is a blob file generated ? I searched google and this site but i couldn't find any example. I guess I don't understand about blobs and database. Your guidance is best appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
MySqlCommand cmd;
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO mytable (id, blobcol) VALUES (1,:blobfile)";
cmd.Parameters.Add("blobfile", File.ReadAllBytes(your_jpeg_file));
```

A BLOB is a binary field in which you can write (in general) an array of bytes.
So you can read your file as byte[] and pass it to a query parameter.

Answer (score 1):

[What is a BLOB file](http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/definition/BLOB)

"In general, a blob is an amorphous and undefinable object."

The actual contents of a JPEG file when read in their raw (as they are) format can be considered to be a BLOB object. What you can do is simply read the entire JPEG file in a byte[] buffer and whatever you get, you just put in your database in a BLOB field